# How to get full web address with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I cannot find how to get the full address of a web site: 
I get for example "/wiki/Main_Page" instead of "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page".
I cannot simply add url to the link as it would give :"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKIK/wiki/Main_Page" which is incorrect.
My goal is to make it work for any website so I am looking for a general solution.

Here is the code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKIK"
r  = requests.get(url)
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print "Found the URL:", link['href']
```

Here is a part of what it returns :

```
>Found the URL: /wiki/WKIK_(AM)
>Found the URL: /wiki/WKIK-FM
>Found the URL: /wiki/File:Disambig_gray.svg
>Found the URL: /wiki/Help:Disambiguation
>Found the URL: //en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?
>title=Special:WhatLinksHere/WKIK&namespace=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are taking links from  element, href attribute .You will almost always get link like /wiki/Main_Page.

Because the base url is always the same 'https://en.wikipedia.org'.
So what you need is to do is:

```
base_url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org'
search_url ="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKIK"
r  = requests.get(search_url)
data = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    print ("Found the URL:", link['href'])
    if link['href'] != '#' and link['href'].strip() != '':
       final_url = base_url + link['href']
```

Comment: Thank you ! That is what I needed !

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers here may run into issues with certain relative URLs, such as ones that include periods (`../page`).

Python's `requests` library has [a function called urljoin](https://kite.com/python/docs/requests.compat.urljoin) to get the full URL:

```
requests.compat.urljoin(currentPage, link)
```

So if you're on `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKIK` and there's a link on the page with an `href` of `/wiki/Main_Page`, that function would return `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page`.

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like this will suit you:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
if 'en.wikipedia.org' not in link['href']:
    print("Found the URL:", 'https://en.wikipedia.org'+link['href'])
elif 'http' not in link['href']:
    print("Found the URL:", 'https://'+link['href'])
else:    
    print("Found the URL:", link['href'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I am looking for is something that would work for any website. How can I know if I have to add ' https://en.wikipedia.org' or the whole url ' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKIK' ?

Comment: I've looked at the URLs that your code catches.
it seems that every URL on base link is a continuation of  'en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKIK' (with the exclusion of general URLs which are full, like this one: //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Contact_us)

Comment: you can't build a parser that would be easy built and ready to apply to ANY web-site...Markups differ, URLs on one site can be full, on another can be relative, just like at wikipedia.